# Is Windows API an object-oriented framework?

Tags: c, oop, winapi

When you create a control object (an `HWND`) in Windows API, you are not allowed to access the members of the control object directly, you can only access it through specific functions, which is a characteristic of OOP.

Also, Windows API supports Polymorphism, for example I can have the following function:

```
void setHwndText(HWND hwnd)
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Hello World");
}
```

The above function can change the text of many types of objects and not just one type, for example it can change the title of a window, the text of an edit control, and the caption of a button control.

I don't know if Windows API supports Inheritance, but even if it didn't, I think the main purpose of Inheritance in OOP is to allow Polymorphism, which Windows API do support as I have showed.

Does that mean that Windows API can be considered an object-oriented framework?

Comment: The Windows API is not a framework. It's an API. Other than that, you'll see lots of OOP paradigms, implemented in C. There's also inheritance (e.g. registering a window class, that delegates messages to `DefWindowProc`, the base class implementation). Still, this question is not a very good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) discusses the topic.

Comment: @IInspectable Although, in a traditional object-oriented framework, you don’t register a function pointer per instance to implement a member function; you would declare a subclass of your hypothetical `class UrWindow` that overrides the virtual member callback function.

Comment: There's also lots of COM in the Windows API. COM immediately supports encapsulation, specialization, and polymorphism. @Davislor: You can't do that in C. In C, registering function pointers is a common way to implement custom behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable Back in the mid-’90s, when I was writing in Modula-2, I would have called that “object-based, but not object-oriented.”

Comment: @Davislor: What feature specifically is missing in COM to call it *"object-based"* rather than *"object-oriented"*?

Comment: @IInspectable Not COM, but the Windows API functions where the equivalent of overriding member functions is supplying an arbitrary pointer to a callback function.

Comment: It shows pretty clear signs of having been inspired by OOP work.  Hard to trace it though, I think Xerox PARC was at least partly involved.  Smalltalk-80 and Altos work was well known when Microsoft started on Windows, message passing was a core concept in the language.  The notion of a window class was clearly inspired.  No credits were given so hard to be sure.  In general OOP was the hot topic in middle 80s.

Comment: @Davislor: Supplying an arbitrary pointer to a callback function is precisely, how COM is implemented. You seem to be confusing the mechanics with the goal.

Comment: @IInspectable It’s been a while since I read the documentation, but I think the difference here is that conventional OOP languages *don’t* let you assign arbitrary function pointers to member functions, or create new kinds of classes at runtime. The compiler statically analyzes whether your polymorphism is type-safe.

Comment: @Davislor: That may be a choice some language designers have chosen. But that has no effect on what is and what isn't object-oriented. What's more, the .NET CLR has support to create new types, at runtime. A platform you have identified as *"object-oriented"* in your answer. Again, you seem to be confusing the mechanics with the goal.

Comment: @IInspectable I also said that COM is object-oriented. Perhaps you misread me as saying the opposite? There are similarities to window classes you register with `RegisterClassEx()` and a class with a virtual `.WindowProc()` member function, but you don’t have a class hierarchy where you overload them, you don’t implement a selection of interfaces, and you don’t use language support.

Comment: @Davislor: I didn't misread that. According to you, COM is object-oriented. COM is implemented by supplying arbitrary pointers to callback functions. According to you, supplying arbitrary pointers to callback functions cannot build an object-oriented system. One of those statements cannot be correct.

Comment: @IInspectable COM uses function pointers, but not all code that uses function pointers is object-oriented. In particular, COM has interfaces.  It imposes a lot more structure.

Comment: That is not an example of polymorphism, the API simply recasts `LPARAM` back to a `LPSTR` internally, because when `Msg` is `WM_SETTEXT` that is what `lParam` actually is. Maybe `HWND` is an object, I'd bet it probably is, but the APIs are most certainly not it's methods. The methods are handled internally by the API implementation.

Comment: @Havenard HWND is a pointer and the pointer is meaningless in user-mode other than to say "I want to represent window XXXX with this handle!". Anyway, win32k.sys/win32kfull.sys plays a part with these GUI topics. That is why User32.dll heavily relies on Win32u and why Win32u supports system call transition (NTOSKRNL -> KeServiceDescriptorTableShadow -> win32k.sys). In Windows Kernel, tables track dished out handles so it knows the pointer to a structure later on when it gets given a handle - also how Windows knows when a process tries to use a handle it was not consented to use.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR Yes friend, we all know that `HWND` is provided to us as a pointer, the talk here is about what it really means behind the scenes. Every object is handled around as a pointer, even `this` is a pointer.

Comment: @Havenard Don't mind me, I wasn't trying to say you said anything wrong. I didn't read any of this properly, I just glanced and didn't see anyone mention win32k.sys/win32full.sys, so just posted it. Since what I said was off-topic, I'll delete it if I am asked to and will understand.

Answer (score 3):

File and window handles in Windows are similar to streams, file descriptors in Unix, `FILE` pointers in the C standard library, and so on.  There’s a similarity between passing an opaque handle to library functions and calling member functions with an implicit `this` pointer.

Another example that gets closer are window classes that you register with `RegisterClassEx()`.  This is transitional between a handle-style API and a framework like COM that everyone agrees is “object-oriented:” you register a structure containing a function pointer, which is much like the member function pointers in a virtual function table.  What you don’t have is any kind of class hierarchy or a selection of interfaces to implement.  You aren’t overriding a default implementation, or inheriting some methods while overriding others.  You’re just passing a structure containing function pointers.

The distinction can get fuzzy.  If you look at the family of languages designed by Nicholas Wirth, Pascal is a traditional structured, imperative language inspired by Algol, and Modula, Modula-2 and Oberon evolve experimentally in an object-oriented direction.  At the time, these intermediate languages were called “object-based.” By the mid-’90s, languages such as Delphi and Object Pascal fit the object-oriented paradigm.

However, libraries similar to those of the late ’70s generally are not called “object-oriented.”  In particular, they don’t have a class hierarchy with inheritance.  Neither does the client application manage instances itself, with their creation and destruction automated to prevent memory leaks.

When the C API does do things similar to polymorphism and inheritance, such as being able to supply a pointer to a callback function, it does it in a different way.  In a conventional object-oriented language, you would statically define a derived class of a window that overrides a virtual member function, not supply an arbitrary function pointer to call back (although there is some similarity to the object-oriented visitor pattern).

Things like the similarly-named “window classes” are just callbacks.  Even though all implementations of polymorphic objects are built on top of structures containing function pointers, not all programs that use callback functions are object-oriented.  An example closer to object-oriented programming is how Winsock 2 makes socket descriptors a special type of file descriptors that can be passed to the kernel file functions (with a cast).  If we had an object-oriented API that renamed the member functions as global functions, made the implicit `this` pointer an explicit argument, then cast it to an opaque handle, it’d still be mostly object-oriented.  The only things it would lose would be static type safety and encapsulation.  Even more OOP-like, to the point where I would definitely call it OOP, is the Component Object Model and its successors, in which objects implement interfaces.

There have been several “object-oriented” APIs for Windows, including the Microsoft Foundation Classes, Borland’s Object Windows Library, Object Linking and Embedding, the newer Component Object Model and Common Language Runtime libraries, and the even newer Windows Runtime.

Comment: Calling the CLR *"new"* is a far stretch. It has been around for almost 2 decades. The new API is called *Windows Runtime*, which is object oriented in a more traditional meaning. Even though it's still exposed as a C interface.

Comment: @Davislor While you're listing OO API's in the Windows world, COM is probably deserving of at least an honorable mention.

Comment: A Winsock socket is actually kernel File object, usually opened on "\Device\Afd". You can use it with `ReadFile` and `WriteFile`, though in some cases this may come at a cost to performance.

Comment: On the subject of kernel handles, the executive's Object Manager implements a type system. Kernel objects are instances of object types (e.g. File, Process, Event, Job), which are in turn instances of the "Type" metatype. The available properties and procedures (methods) are fixed. Each type is also associated with system calls to query and set an extensible set of information and behavior (e.g. `NtQueryInformationFile`, `NtSetInformationFile`), but there's no ability to subclass and extend a type.

Comment: @eryksun [The MS documentation says,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/socket-data-type-2) “In Winsock applications, a socket descriptor is not a file descriptor and must be used with the Winsock functions.” Winsock2 is different.  So, Winsock has a `closesocket()` function and Winsock2 can just use the one for files.

Comment: @eryksun Edited a clarification that “Winsock” meant version 1.

Comment: I said a socket handle is for a kernel File object, not a C runtime file descriptor. They need to make this distinction clear in the documentation because otherwise people would try to pass sockets to C runtime functions that take CRT file descriptors, and vice versa, which will not work.

Comment: Other than for historical reasons, there's no need to talk about Winsock 1.0 from the early 90s.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for correcting me, then. On second thought, the paragraph seems extraneous and I cut it.

Comment: Windows sockets actually are interesting here. They do kind of subclass the kernel File object, but with an object composition approach. A lot of Winsock behavior is implemented in client-side DLLs. The kernel File handle is associated with state in the client process. This is why it's still recommend to use `WSADuplicateSocket` in the source process and `WSASocket` in the target process instead of using generic handle inheritance or `DuplicateHandle`.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, that is similar to passing around references to polymorphic objects.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR If you declared the type alias `using handle = std::uintptr_t;` or `using handle = const void*;` then wrote an API that replaced the hidden `this` pointer argument with its value cast to a `handle`, I think the API would be nearly as object-oriented as before. All you’d lose is static type safety.